# Foodservice calculation question. Converting weights

Tags: arithmetic

The question is:

> A 5-pound bag of cocoa powder costs $25.35. One cup of cocoa powder weighs 4 ounces. How much would 2 teaspoons cost?

I first converted the 5 pounds to ounces by multiplying by 16 to get 80.
Then I took the 80 ounces and divided it by 4 to see how many 4 ounce cups are in 80 ounces, which is 20 cups.
Then I multiplied the 20 cups by 48 to convert the cups into teaspoons of cocoa powder.

If the bag costs 25.35 dollars and there is 960 teaspoons, each teaspoon costing 0.02640625, rounding up to $0.03

If I multiply by 2 to determine the cost of 2 teaspoons, and get **the answer $0.06**, did I answer the question correctly?

Comment: More proof that the SI system is your friend.

Comment: Yes, I would say so.  There's more than one possibility for handling the rounding at the end, but if that isn't specified, what you did seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would round after multiplying: $2 \times \$0.0264 = \$0.0528$ or about $5$ cents.

But otherwise it looks good.